# Best practice for using Powershell to compile solution with multiple projects

Tags: powershell, configuration, compilation

I have an application that contains close to 90 different projects written in at least 3 different languages (C#, Visual C++, and Visual Basic) targetting .NET 3, 3.5, 4.0, and 4.5,, with 6 different configurations. We are about to start scripting our compilations due to some messy configuration hassles involving preprocessing out features for different clients. I have seen multiple methods of using Powershell scripts to compile such applications but they seem to boil down to two options: compile the entire solution or compile each project individually.

So my question is: is there an industry best practice for such things? And if so what is it?

The project lead seems to be leaning toward compiling and individually configuring each project, but it seems wasteful since we already have configurations in VS to configure out individual projects. If this question is too subjective, I'd be happy to take it down. And sorry if my information is kind of vague, but I have to walk on egg shells with this project. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with a large number of projects, and you are working with the Microsoft technology stack, the "Official" way to go would be to use Microsoft's full [Team Foundation Server](http://www.visualstudio.com/products/tfs-overview-vs#) technology and formalize the development lifecycle.

It does Source Control, Build management, Testing, etc. I would then combine it with [Release Management](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/manage-your-release-vs.aspx) to more fully automate things.

The move to TFS is a big leap, and will require some time to get set up and configured, etc., but I think it is the best thing out there once you start reaching dozens of projects. PowerShell, and other methods are good, but become unmanageable when you are starting to scale out to large numbers of projects.

Comment: If it was up to me that's what we would go with. But unfortunately I was tasked with "make powershell configuration scripts" not "find a good source control tool"